# Mathematica empty plots problem [RESOLVED]

Tags: plotting

Two of my homework problems don't want to get plotted.. I keep getting empty graphs with only the two axes:

[image]

And for the second one:

[image]

UPDATED TEXT VERSION:

```
In[114]:= Clear[h]

In[177]:= h[x_]:=(1-Log[x])/(E^(1/x))
In[178]:= Limit[h[x], x->0, Direction->FromAbove]
Out[178]= ConditionalExpression[0,ln∈&&Log[e]>0]
In[179]:= Plot [h[x],{x, 0, 4}]
Out[179]=
```

Second one:

```
In[133]:= Clear [g]
g[x_]:=(1/x)-Log[x]
In[180]:= Limit[g[x], x-> 0, Direction-> FromAbove]
Out[180]= ∞
In[181]:= Plot [g[x],{x, 0, 3}]
Out[181]=
```

Comment: Use `Log` instead of `ln` and `E` instead of `e`, and brackets [] instead of parentheses () for functions.

Comment: Be patient... post the code in text format

Comment: As in @CarlWoll's hint, Mathematica is case sensitive and built-in functions are capitalized.

Comment: I added the text version

Comment: Use parentheses for controlling order of operations, and brackets for functions. You are using brackets for both now.

Comment: @CarlWoll I fixed it again (check edit) and I still get no plot after reevaluating everything.

Comment: Nvm fixed. Thanks enano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to do your homework for you, I have made an edit to your first problem to make it work (changed the numbers so you have to implement it yourself, but it should give an idea).

```
Clear[h]
(* Use () instead of [] for ordering *)
h[x_] := (13 - Log[5 * x])/E^(1 / x^2);
```

Now you can look at why Direction wasn't working properly for you. If you read the error message and look at the documentation for the `Limit` function you will see that `FromAbove` is not a supported value, nor is it something that Mathematica even knows about.

```
(* the values of the Direction option are + or - 1, you can play around with the below *)
Limit[h[x], x -> 0, Direction -> -1]
```

Then with the above modifications, the `Plot` call evaluates properly.

```
(* this just works with the modifications to h[x_] *)
Plot[h[x], {x, 0, 4}]
```

Things to take away:

1. The coloring of things in a notebook can give you hints about what is going on. The fact that `FromAbove` was blue means that it doesn't have a value.
2. When a message is issued, read it carefully and try to figure out what it means. Google and other resources are your friend.
3. Read about WL syntax, square brackets `[]` are only for calls to/defining functions, not for ordering expressions, use regular parens for that `()`.
4. Good luck on your homework! Try to watch some Mathematica/Wolfram Language instructional videos. In fact Stephen Wolfram has an excellent guide to starting to use the language. It is available from free online [right here at this link.](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/preface.html)

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: `"FromAbove"` is equivalent to `-1` and `"FromBelow"` is equivalent to `+1` (Note: presence of quotes)

Comment: Thanks @BobHanlon, I often find it frustrating when I can't remember if a value needs to be string-valued or a symbol. This was one of those cases. I could swear I had seen them before, but clearly the symbol `FromAbove` was not defined. Thanks for pointing that out!